# MonoJust - how to use in unit tests / map() is not called

Tags: reactjs, junit, mocking

There is a unit test code:

```
    @Mock
    Client client;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
    
        doAnswer(r -> {
            response.setData(data);
            return Mono.just(response);
        }).when(client).doSomething(any(Response.class));
        ...
        foo();
     }
```

in code method 'doSomething' is used like:

```
    public void foo() {
        Response result = new Response();
        client.doSomething(result).map( resp -> {
            // THIS CODE IS NOT EXECUTED IN JUNIT TEST
            if (somelag) {
               ...
            }
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

### Question:

How to execute this code in junit test in proper way?

**Notes**:

- in runtime it is working fine
- the issue is related to threads (probably)
- in runtime there is (`reactor.core.publisher.Mono`)

```
public final <R> Mono<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return this instanceof Fuseable ? onAssembly(new MonoMapFuseable(this, mapper)) : onAssembly(new MonoMap(this, mapper));
}
```

- in runtime: `this instanceof Fuseable == false`
- in junit `this instanceof Fuseable == true`
- in junit test in method (`reactor.core.publisher.Mono`) `hook == null` and `Hooks.GLOBAL_TRACE == false`

```
    protected static <T> Mono<T> onAssembly(Mono<T> source) {
        Function<Publisher, Publisher> hook = Hooks.onEachOperatorHook;
        if (hook != null) {
            source = (Mono)hook.apply(source);
        }

        if (Hooks.GLOBAL_TRACE) {
            FluxOnAssembly.AssemblySnapshot stacktrace = new FluxOnAssembly.AssemblySnapshot((String)null, (Supplier)Traces.callSiteSupplierFactory.get());
            source = (Mono)Hooks.addAssemblyInfo(source, stacktrace);
        }

        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Don't misuse the mono tag as it is for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an access to `mono` (here `responseMono`) used in `foo()` and call on it `.block(Duration...)` method

```
@Mock
Client client;

@Test
public void test() {

    doAnswer(r -> {
        response.setData(data);
        return Mono.just(response);
    }).when(client).doSomething(any(Response.class));
    ...
    responseMono = foo();

    responseMono.block(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); // <-- REQUIRED

    ...
    assertThat(...); // NOW IS OK
 }
```

`responseMono` in my case was returned by `foo()`

```
public Mono<Response> foo() {
    Response result = new Response();
    Mono<Response> responseMono = client.doSomething(result).map( resp -> {

        if (someFlag) {
           ...
        }
        return resp;
    }
    ...
    return responseMono;
}
```